# Custom View receives Activity/Fragment lifecycle callbacks?

Tags: android, layout, view, activity-lifecycle

I'm working on custom view that will be used as normal android view component. Is it possible to internally handle hosts (activity/fragment) lifecycle states?

My goal is to avoid end users (devs) to override every lifecycle callback in order to sync states with my view, for example:

```
@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    if (myCustomView != null) {
        myCustomView.onStop();
    }
}
```

Comment: first of all `super.onStop()` should be your last statement for this method

Comment: Dennis, thanks for your comment but this is just pseudo code so order is not that important at this point.

Comment: Trust me, it is. :) You'll realize it someday.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using [Architecture Components](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/) you can implement [LifecycleObserver](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/LifecycleObserver) interface, then:

1. Annotate your view's onStop() method with `@OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_STOP)`
2. In view's constructor register the observer: `((LifecycleOwner)context).getLifecycle().addObserver(this)`

Comment: Hmm, that is one way to go, but I'm trying to create view that does not relay on other third party components.

Comment: Yeah, this looks useful.